# Group filtering in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

In Crystal Report Designer in VS 2008, I can go to the crystal reports menu, report, Selection Formula, Group and enter a filter formula to filter on a group level. This means I can filter to only show records for a certain account, but my group levels show the totals for all records, which is what I want.

However, when I come to add my filter dynamical in my C# code, the only option I get to use is

```
CRViewer.SelectFormualr= .....
```

This does the record type filtering, not group type. Is there any way to do group level filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the GroupSelectionFormula property of the underlying report, found as ReportDocument.DataDefinition.GroupSelectionFormula.